# Timeline chart build failed when data length more then 300

Tags: highcharts

When we are using data length more then 300 to create a timeline chart using Highchart library it is giving error to reproduce the issue check on     [Example]
''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is caused by `cropThreshold` which is set by default to 300. As a solution increase the value.

However, it looks like a bug in Highcharts, so you can report it here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues

```
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            cropThreshold: 400
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3bokt407/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.cropThreshold